# Blueimp jQuery file upload not sending form data with larger files

Tags: jquery, file, upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

The upload process works for smaller file sizes and I am noticing that the following request informaiton is sent:

```
Array
(
    [nonce] => b3df6659bf
    [wpc-product-id-upl] => 404
    [action] => handle-custom-design-upload
)
```

When uploading a larger file, however, the post information is empty and nothing is being sent:

```
Array
(
)
```

I did set the correct configuration in php.ini, restarted the server and made sure that larger files are supported (up to 256MB). The files I am trying to uploading are 20MB.

Your helps is appreciated.

Comment: please post your parameters what you have changed in php.ini file

Comment: how long it takes to upload the file? Any chance is server timeout? Indeed for large file upload, you should setup 'upload modules' on web server (apache/nginx).